# Installing a specific Mono version on CentOS7 or RHEL 7.2

Tags: mono, centos, centos7

I am new to Linux based systems and do not have much idea about the packaging systems. I would like to install specific version of Mono (in my case 4.4.0) on a Cent OS 7 operating system.

I currently do the following:

```
yum install yum-utils
rpm --import "http://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF"
yum-config-manager --add-repo http://download.mono-project.com/repo/centos/
yum check-update
yum install -y mono-complete
```

How do I say to install the 4.4.0 version of Mono?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you use yum like this, you always install latest available version from repository. If you want to install specific version, you could use command **yum install mono-complete-4.2.3.4-0** or download rpm-package and use **rpm -i .rpm** command to install it.

How I can see, in official repository Mono 4.4.0 not avalaible, yet, but you could download it from beta channel. To add it you should use command:

```
yum-config-manager --add-repo http://download.mono-project.com/repo/centos-beta/
```

And then install Mono by command:

```
yum install -y mono-complete
```

But be aware, next yum update will install latest version from beta channel.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-lin-centos

> ```
> rpm --import "https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF"
> su -c 'curl https://download.mono-project.com/repo/centos7-stable.repo | tee /etc/yum.repos.d/mono-centos7-stable.repo'
> ```

```
sudo yum install -y mono-complete
```